# How to reuse the content of controltemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

Supose we have two controltemplates with differen controltemplate triggers but with the same content template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="A" TargetType="SomeControl">
   <Grid x:Name="reusableGrid"> Grid with a lot of stuff in it,
                                like borders, different shapes and colors. 
                                I'd like to reuse this part in both Templates
   </Grid>
   <ContentPresenter .../>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="AAA" Value="X"> some setter stuff </Trigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="B" TargetType="SomeControl">
   <reusableGrid/>

   <ContentPresenter .../>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="BBB" Value="Y"> some setter stuff </Trigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Is there a way to use the grid and its content in both templates without duplicating it? *please note that I wouldn't want to make a usercontrol out of it.* That's because I need to be able to access different parts in my content template triggers (for example, to set border colors).

Comment: What you describe is exactly what `UserControl`s are created for, reusability. For the parts you want to change, just create some `DependencyProperty`s and bind them to these properties.

Comment: You can declare a `Grid` resource with `x:Shared="False"` and then reuse it in each template. It does seem to me that a `UserControl` should work as well; your question doesn't adequately describe your problem at all, never mind what specifically doesn't work for you when using a `UserControl`. If you want a good answer, please fix the question by providing a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, along with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.